# rails controller respond_to if/else based on action is successful/not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

How could I use conditional based on the success of this custom action both for html and js. With basic actions (update, create) works perfectly but here I could not pull off the if/else statement properly, so I have it without checking if the action is successful

With the format.js form I'm using AJAX and complete.js.erb.

controller

```
def complete
  @task.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to completed_tasks_user_tasks_path(current_user), notice: "Task completed!" }
    format.js
  end
end
```

view

```
<% if task.completed_at == nil %>
  <%= link_to complete_user_task_path(id: task.id), action: :complete, remote: true, method: :patch do %>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  <% end %>
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action here is always going to be successful because update_attribute isn't going to run validations/callbacks. So you shouldn't have to check the success of this action. If you're worried about it throwing an error you could `begin...rescue` around the `update_attribute`, but otherwise you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Alternatively, if you want it to run those, change it to `if @task.update(completed_at: Time.now)` and switch appropriately on the return value.

Comment: kddeisz, could you elaborate the second part of your answer?

Comment: `update` is an alias for `update_attributes` (note the s). `update_attributes` runs validations and callbacks and all the usual rails goodness. `update_attribute` just updates the one attribute directly on the database, regardless of whether or not that's a valid value for that attribute.

Comment: I see, so after all from the users' point of view, you think update_attribute is enough in this case?

Comment: Completely depends on the use case. If you need to run validations against :completed_at, then you need to use `update`, otherwise just update the column and be done.